# Random number without duplicate in java

Tags: java, random

i want to generate random numbers without duplicate from 1 to n^2 (e.g. n=3, numbers in range of 1 to 9) in 2D array and i don't want to use  list, but my code generated the numbers duplicate, how can i fix this ? here is my code :

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
      array[i][j] = rand.nextInt((n * n) - 1) + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: @samabcde No i want to don't use <Integer> list

Comment: generating a list with values, shuffling it and getting the randomized values one by one seems to be quite reasonable.  An alternative is to create a set to track the generated values and generate random values until a unique number is detected.

Comment: `No i want to don't use <Integer> list` @parsaaa then state it in the question, not after people provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate a sequential collection, shuffle it and put the shuffled elements in your array.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= n * n; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        array[i][j] = numbers.get(index);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It generates numbers range of 0 to n² - 1.

Comment: I updated the answer. It generated numbers from 0 - n^2 - 1 becaues of how I initialized it. Look at the first for loop.